# react-grid-layout and drag from outside

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

With `react-grid-layout`, is it possible to specify the size of the draggable item from outside of the grid when the user drags it over the grid? Currently, the default appears to be `w: 1, h:1` however, I'm not seeing any where I can set this.

Also, is it possible to specify any details about the draggable item that get sent to the function for the `onDrop` handler? Currently it's limited to `(layout: Layout[], item: Layout, e: Event)`

This is an example from RGL of dragging from outside:
https://strml.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/15-drag-from-outside.html

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out. You have to specify it with the `droppingItem` prop on the `<GridLayout>` or in my case the `<ResponsiveGridLayout>`. This can either be an object, or you can have it call a function that determines the details from some logic, ie `droppingItem={this.getDroppingItem()}`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it (which I think is really much simpler) is to just set the desired width/height state on "onDragStart" and then use the state variable when you're dynamically adding the element to the actual GridLayout.

Example for storing the desired width in state:

```
onDragStart={(e) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "");
    setCurrentDimensions(
        {
            w: 5,
            h: 2
        }
    );
}}
```

And then use the same one to dynamically add the item to the grid:

```
layout.concat({
    i: "n" + layout.length,
    x: layoutItem.x,
    y: layoutItem.y,
    w: currentDimensions.w,
    h: currentDimensions.h,
});
```